# Javamail issue with authentication exception

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I tried to send mail communication through gmail smtp. Please solve this exception.. I am getting continuous failure regarding this issue..

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException

Filters.Emailer.sendEmail(Emailer.java:51)

org.apache.jsp.registration_jsp._jspService(registration_jsp.java:135)

org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)

javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)

org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)

org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)

org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)

javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)

org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

root cause

javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException

```
javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:319)

javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:169)

javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:118)

javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:188)

javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:118)

Filters.Emailer.sendEmail(Emailer.java:47)

org.apache.jsp.registration_jsp._jspService(registration_jsp.java:135)

org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)

javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)

org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)

org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)

org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)

javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)

org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please pate your code. As you said i think you may did not wrote correct password authentication. Try this.. If you have doubt mention in comment.

```
Session session=Session.getDefaultInstance(
properties,new    javax.mail.Authenticator(){   
protected PasswordAuthentication     
getPasswordAuthentication(){
return new PasswordAuthentication 
("ganeshp@gmail.com","ganesHp");
            }
        });
```

Comment: thanks for your answer.. my code is same as you mentioned.. now i am getting following exception               Exception reading response;
  nested exception is:
 java.net.SocketException: Connection reset

Comment: Have you check your mail settings "Allow less secure apps: OFF" which you gave in your mail. Make sure this setting as OFF

Comment: Allow less secure apps should be ON